# Should <meta property="og:image" content="..."> have an alt tag?

Tags: html, images, meta-tags, alt-attribute, open-graph-protocol

I want to follow good SEO practices by adding `alt` tags to all my images.

For Facebook sharing, I have this code:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="...">
```

Can I add an `alt="Facebook image"` to that?

Comment: No. `og:image` is just a link to an image file, it doesn't need an alt tag.  Open graph already has tags for `title` and `site_name`. `<meta property="og:title" content="Site Title">` for example.

Answer (score 9):

No, you do not need an `alt` attribute on that meta tag. In fact, it is not even allowed as others have already said.

However, (today) Open Graph specifies and even suggests to provide the image alt text via an `og:image:alt` property. See http://ogp.me/#structured.

Note that the `og:image` meta tag is not an image tag, but rather a hint on which image should be used when displaying that page somewhere else. Thus, the specified alt text will probably improve the image usage for that other site that embeds your page, e.g. Facebook.

Answer (score 4):

No, a `meta` element cannot have an `alt` attribute in any HTML specification. Technically, you could have the attribute `title="Facebook image"`, since the `title` attribute is allowed for all elements according to HTML5 LC (though not HTML 4.01), but it is very unlikely that any browser or search engine cares about it for `meta`; so it would matter as comment-like documentation only.

Answer (score 2):

og specification does not have alt attribute. You can check valid attributes at [the open graph protocol website](http://ogp.me/).